Is there anything that can cause the element with 'min-height' property to misbehave?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat&Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lang">
        <select  class="srclang">
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="ta">Tamil</option>
            <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
        </select>
        <select class="trglang">
            <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="ta">Tamil</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="msgarea"></div>
    <div class="typebar">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message.." class="msgbox" required>
        <button class="sendbtn">Send</button>
    </div>
    

    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #E9EFEC;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

.msgarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85vh;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end; /* Align messages from the top */
    gap: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable scrolling */
}

.msgarea p {
    max-width: 80%;
    display: block; /* Change this */
    min-height: 40px; /* Keep this */
    background-color: #478CCF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; /* Ensure long words wrap */
}


.lang {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}


.typebar {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #E9EFEC;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

.msgbox {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.sendbtn {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #478CCF;
    color: white;
    width: 10%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}


@media (max-width:700px) {
    .msgarea {
        height: 80vh;
        border: 2px solid #478CCF;
    }

    .msgarea p{
        min-height: 40px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .msgbox {
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
    }

    .sendbtn {
        width: 30%;
        height: 70%;
    }



    
}

Here I set the height of the 'msgarea p' to 40px minimum. This works fine if there are few messages inside the 'msgarea'.I also added overflow property to 'msgarea' to ensure that it becomes scrollable once the messages exceed. It too works fine. But the problem is with the 'msgarea p' height especially when the messages exceed and it becomes scrollable. Once 'msgarea' becomes scrollable the min-height property misbehaves and the text in 'p' tag overflows the background color. This is the issue i face.
I tried altering height of p tag to auto but nothing happened.

Try and remove the min-height so that the text can cover the cover the entire backround-color and not overflow

Sure. Will try this

It actually kind of worked. Thanks
